# PHP echo selected value from html dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

In my dropdown list, i put all the "pack_name(s)" the user has posted and I display it all in the list for the user to select and update. So when the user selects one and hits submit, i want to get that "value" submitted and use it for later purposes but ive been researching and only found "pre-set" values with html and the value was given using Jquery. So i wondering if its possible to basically take the "pack_name" selected and when the user hits submit, echo out the selected value.

PHP

```
<?php
session_start();

 if(empty($_FILES) && empty($_POST) && isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'post'){ //catch file overload error...
        $postMax = ini_get('post_max_size'); //grab the size limits...
        echo "<p style=\"color: #F00;\">\nPlease note files larger than {$postMax} will result in this error!</p>"; // echo out error and solutions...
        return $postMax;
    }

if(isset($_COOKIE['id'])){

    if($_SESSION['came_from_upload'] != true){

        setcookie("id", "", time() - 60*60);
        $_COOKIE['id'] = "";
        header("Location: developerLogin.php");
        exit;


    }

    try{

        // new php data object 
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=magicserver', 'root', '');
        //ATTR_ERRMODE set to exception
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        }catch(PDOException $e){
             die("There was an error connecting to the database");   

        }
       $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
       $stmt = $handler->prepare("SELECT * FROM pack_profile WHERE pack_developer_id = :userid");
       $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
       $stmt->execute();
       echo "<select>";

       while($result = $stmt->fetch()){
         echo "<option>" . $result['pack_name'] ."</option>";
       }

       echo "</select>";

   if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] =="POST"){
         $token = $_SESSION['token'];


}
}


?>
```

Comment: So what's part of the code isn't working? Please be more specific. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no errors, i am trying to echo the result that was selected. I am very specific in my explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the `select` element a `name` attribute, and give each `option` element a `value` attribute.

For example:

```
   echo "<select name=\"pack\">";

   while($result = $stmt->fetch()){
     echo "<option value=\"" . $result['pack_name'] . "\">" . $result['pack_name'] ."</option>";
   }

   echo "</select>";
```

Of course you should be escaping anything which could contain `&`, `<` or `"` with something like `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: Oh so now do i just echo the "result"

Comment: Result will be in `$_POST['pack']` or `$_GET['pack']`.  Your question is confusing since you already have advanced concepts like sessions, file uploads and indeed even `$_POST` in your code yet you don't seem to know basics how forms work.  I'm assuming you are outputting a form element eg `<form action="something" method="POST">` somewhere?  It's not in your code.

Comment: I am so sorry i had a bad headache yesterday but i tried "echo $_POST['pack'}" and i got an error saying "( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: pack in C:\wamp64\www\MT\developer_packupdater.php on line 48
"

Comment: I think maybe it would be wise to employ someone who knows web development or PHP to do this work for you - I just feel that it's going to take a bit too much to lead you through this.

Comment: Well i am doing this just to learn but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Well there are some good places online to learn this stuff:

Here's a start: https://www.joedolson.com/2007/02/processing-forms-with-php/

Or this

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mo89ABKlfYE

I don't want to discourage you from learning, just that asking a small detail here and there and waiting for a response doesn't seem efficient.